# jqGrid Inline edit: Append custom element next to dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the following grid which contains data from a local array (which I save with my own custom call):

```
var datagrid = [
    {name:"Id",description:"description",entityid:"12",amount:"100"},
    {name:"Id2",description:"description",entityid:"17",amount:"200"}
];

$grid = $("#grid1").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: datagrid,
    height: "auto",
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    colNames:['Name','Description', 'Entity', 'Amount', ''],
    colModel:[
        {index: 'name', name: 'name', editable: true, edittype: 'text'},
        {index: 'description', name: 'description', editable: true, edittype: 'text'},
        {index: 'entityid', name: 'entityid', editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: 
            {
                dataUrl: 'url/to/drop/down/data',
                buildSelect: function(data)
                {
                    return buildSelectFromJson(data, 'oid', 'oname');
                }
            }
        },
        {index: 'amount', name: 'amount', editable: true, edittype: 'text'},
        {name:'act', index:'act', sortable:false, width: "140px"}
    ],
    onSelectRow: function(rowid){
        rowSelected('grid1', rowid);
    },
    rowNum: 500,
    editurl: "clientArray",
    caption: "Details",
    ajaxSelectOptions: {contentType: "application/json", dataType: 'json'}
});

$grid.jqGrid('hideCol',['act']);
```

Next to the "entityid" drop down I want to add a button to show a popup to enter a new entity. I want the new entity to be loaded in the drop-down after the popup closes.

Previously I used **editoptions: {value: getValueFunction}** but I read some advice in stack overflow which advised against it and anyway I could not load the new entity in the drop-down after the popup closed. But I was able to add the button this way:

```
function rowSelected(gridid, rowid){
    var $grid = $("#" + gridid);
    var rowData = $grid.jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);

    $grid.jqGrid('showCol',["act"]);

    var oneditfunction = function(){
        var button = '<input id="newFieldRange" type="button" value="+"></input>';
        $grid.find("select").parent().append(button);
        $("#newEntity").on('click', function () {
            newEntity(gridid, rowid);
        });
    };

    $grid.jqGrid('editRow', rowid, {oneditfunc: oneditfunction});
}
```

Using the same code for **rowSelected** function and the code I showed above for the grid, the button is not added. The drop-down is filled with data successfully.

I have the following questions:

1) How can I add a custom button to "entity" cell? Is this not advised? The columns and data I show are not the real data for simplicity reasons. Due to some restrictions, it is not possible to add another column next to the drop-down (we use 'act' column for "Save" and "Cancel" buttons). I would like to add the button in the same cell as the drop-down. Unless there are alternative solutions.

2) How can I force the drop-down to reload after I close the "New entity" popup? I couldn't find anything in the jqGrid wiki.

**EDIT:** I was able to add the button using `onsuccessfunc` of jQGrid's `editRow`. But I am forced to use "select" jqgrid selector without specifying an id, because the  and  elements do not have any ids. I might need to add another dropdown which would cause issues. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for any responses.